# Implementing a Java interface on the JRuby generated .class/.java file

Tags: java, jruby

I'm trying to implement a Java interface in a JRuby class, like this:

```
require 'java'
java_package 'net.jruby.test'
java_import "net.jruby.test.Service"

class RubyService
  include Service

  java_signature 'int sum(int, int)'
  def sum(a,b)
    a + b
  end
end
```

The `net.jruby.test.Service` interface is dead simple:

```
package net.jruby.test;

public interface Service
{
  int sum(int a, int b);
}
```

After that I generate the .java class file with:

> jrubyc --java ruby_service.rb

But the generated .java file (and consequently the .class file) **do not implement** the interface, look:

```
public class RubyService extends RubyObject  {
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I've asked in the IRC channel and the mailing list with no (at least immediate) luck, so please don't point me there, I know those options

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer, instead of this:

```
include Service
```

I needed this:

```
java_implements 'Service'
```

Comment: Do you recall where you found this?

Comment: "Using JRuby" book, I think.